# Magento Shipping Address Element Correction (AEC) solution

Tags: magento

We would like to implement a way for Magento so show the customer an error if the shipping address they entered is not valid. Giving them an opportunity to correct it or override the alert if it is really correct.

Has anyone seen a product or extension out there that could help us do this?

Answer (score 1):

Cherie, Welcome to Stackoverflow.

A few options from a quick search.

FREE:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/AccurateTax/extension/1581/us-address-validation-from-accuratetax

PAID:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/QuartSoft/extension/6282/address_validation

Normally this question would be more geared for another more "general" use.  Also, you may want to read over the Stackoverflow FAQ for future usage reference: https://stackoverflow.com/faq